# Nodejs Jasmine : Mocking a Promise function so as not to hit the real code is giving DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine

I have a below function which returns a promise.

```
public async getAverageHeadCount(queryParams: Params, childNode: any, careerTrackId: string):
    Promise<Metric> {
    const queryId = this.hierarchyServiceApiUrl + "rolling-forecast/ahc/" +
      queryParams.ou + "|" + ELCCommonUtil.getChildNode(childNode.id) + "/" + queryParams.gu + "/" + careerTrackId
      + "/" + queryParams.contractFlag + "/" + queryParams.year + "?id=" + ELCCommonUtil.constructForecastId(childNode);
    const userKey = queryParams.userKey;
    console.log("getAverageHeadCount-childNode>>>>>>>>>>>>" + JSON.stringify(childNode));
    const averageHCOptions = {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        userKey
      },
      json: true,
      uri: queryId
    };
    console.log("getAverageHeadCount-averageHCOptions>>>>>>>>>>>>" + averageHCOptions);
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-string-literal
    const averageHC = await this.request(averageHCOptions);
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    console.log("averageHeadCount DATA RETUREDED >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + JSON.stringify(averageHC.data.avgHeadcount));
    return averageHC.data.avgHeadcount;
    // return baseBonusJSON;
  }
```

This method is called from a service, which i am already mocking iam trying to return a mocked response of above function as well like below.

```
fit("Should call getAverageHeadCount to construct right URI", (done) => {
       const uri1 = "53860936/91/510N/FY18?id=18|51549564|F-D-test.user.sixteen-prd_us_no";
       const uri = "https://wwvtn2k42h.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sandbox/rolling-forecast/ahc/" + uri1;

       service = new EstimatedLaborCostsService(((opts) => {
        expect(opts.uri).toBe(uri);
        return avgHeadCount;
      }));
       console.log("service", service);
       console.log("getAverageHeadCount is getting called");

       const resultant = service.getAverageHeadCount(queryString, "53860936", "510").then((result) => {
        expect(result).toEqual(avgHeadCount.data);
        done();
      });
    });
```

I am getting below error :

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL
```

What i am thinking is "`const resultant = service.getAverageHeadCount(queryString, "53860936", "510").then((result)`"
is directly hitting code which i don't want.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky aspect of Promises, especially in unit tests, is that any errors thrown within a `.then(...)` callback will cause the Promise to be rejected. Assertions throw errors, so if `expect(result).toEqual(avgHeadCount.data);` fails, the `done()` callback won't be invoked, and your assertion failure is swallowed.

Rather than using a `done` callback, you can use the fact that returning a Promise from your test causes the test to be asynchronous instead. If the returned Promise is rejected, the test fails. Or simply make your test `async` (which does the same thing)

```
fit("Should call getAverageHeadCount to construct right URI", async () => {
  const uri1 = "53860936/91/510N/FY18?id=18|51549564|F-D-test.user.sixteen-prd_us_no";
  const uri = "https://wwvtn2k42h.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sandbox/rolling-forecast/ahc/" + uri1;

  service = new EstimatedLaborCostsService(((opts) => {
    expect(opts.uri).toBe(uri);
    return avgHeadCount;
  }));

  console.log("service", service);
  console.log("getAverageHeadCount is getting called");

  const result = await service.getAverageHeadCount(queryString, "53860936", "510");
  expect(result).toEqual(avgHeadCount.data);
});
```

Comment: Now it says 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to make it async (or if you can't and want to use the chaining approach instead, return the Promise from the function)